Deployed chain on Langserve but the VertexAI model keeps returning NULL in the playground endpoint
I am trying to deploy a Langchain agent using Langserve. Below is the code I am using
from fastapi import FastAPI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langserve import add_routes
from langchain_google_vertexai.chat_models import ChatVertexAI
from langchain_core.runnables import Runnable
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


PROJECT_ID = "project-my-sandbox"  # Set to your Project ID

app = FastAPI(
    title="LangChain Server",
    version="1.0",
    description="A simple api server using Langchain's Runnable interfaces",
)

llm = ChatVertexAI(project_id=PROJECT_ID, location="us-central1")

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("Tell me a joke about {topic}")

agent: Runnable = prompt | llm

add_routes(
    app,
    agent,
    path="/structured",
)

# Set all CORS enabled origins
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    expose_headers=["*"],
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)


However, when I run the server and try to send an input to the model, it always returns null

Any ideas what is going wrong here? Is there some sort of authentication that I am lacking? It doesn't seem that way to me since initially I was also including a datastore as a tool in the chain, and from the intermediate_steps I could see the datastore was being queried and returning documents. It just seems like the last agent step is the one that all of a sudden leads to this failure.
